# SQL Server Reporting Services - Test connection failing

Tags: connection, sql-server

I created a small project called 'Tutorial' which contains a single Microsoft RDL report.
I created a datasource and a dataset and can preview my report in Visual Studio 2017.
I deployed all three to the ReportServer [running on the same machine] and can see the three directories - Datasets, Data Sources and Tutorial.

I set up my 'Current Report Server Database' in the Report Server Configuration Manager and selected 'Windows Credentials' for my authentication type with a username of LAPTOP-########\MyAccountName and my laptop account password.
I did the same for the 'Current Report Server Database Credential'.
My 'Data Source Properties' credentials [set up in Visual Studio 2017] is also 'Use Windows Authentication'.

In 'SQL Server Reporting Services' I select 'Using the following credentials' and enter the same login credentials I did in the Report Server Configuration Manager.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lllKo.png)

I click 'Test connection' and get the following error.

**Couldn't connect - The report server couldn't connect to the data source using the information you entered. Make sure you've entered the connection string and any credentials correctly.**

My connection string in 'SQL Server Reporting Services' is:
**Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2016;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False**

If anyone has any suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated.  I'm just trying to learn how to publish Microsoft reports and have spent days trying to find out where I'm going wrong with this ... to no avail.

Thanks guys.

Comment: I'm not sure I followed the step you're getting the error: you created the report and it works on report builder or visual studio but not when published to the report server or you can't connect it to start the development?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding. I discovered the cause of the problem. I hadn't published my report correctly to the SSIS server.